# Magento 2 REST api for guest cart - display product in Magento's checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout, rest-api

I have an Ember app that handles adding to basket via the REST API. I then want to jump back into Magento's front end for the checkout process, however the cart is empty. Is there a way to pass a quoteId to the `/checkout` page? Or will I need to implement the checkout process in my custom app?

Comment: Do you receive a session id from the API? Then you can add it as `SID` GET parameter to the URL

Comment: Through the REST API, you can make n amount of guest carts (anonymous access, no oauth/token/session needed). When you create a guest cart, you get a unique token (or cart id, which is a masked quote id, similar to UUID). Afaik, there's no way to convert a cart id into a frontend session.

Did you ever figure this out @rickyduck?

Comment: I was wondering if you had found an answer to this? I have a similar situation and I was thinking to write a custom module to which I pass the cart id to transfer it into a session cart. But I haven’t tried it yet

Answer (score 0):

You could store the quoteId locally.. localstorage or in a cookie?
Add https://www.npmjs.com/package/localforage to your project

Create a new cart and store the data

```
$localForage.setItem('cartId', cartId);
```

Now you can pick up the cart when needed.

```
$localForage.getItem('cartId')
```

Comment: you have any idea if i want to do this using cookie or sesson how to do that ?